# How to know in the matrix form when a linear program isn't feasible and what to do from it?

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Good morning, I'm preparing my exam first exam in linear programing and try to sharpen my skills over how to handle such programs.

I want to know when can we know that a linear program isn't feasible and what to do with it.

For instance this one

\begin{cases}
\max_xf(x)=&x_1&+x_2\\
&x_1 &+x_2&\ge 2\\
&x_1 &+ x_2&\le 7\\
&3x_2 &-x_1&\le 9\\
&3x_1 &+2x_2&\le 18\\
&x\ge 0
\end{cases}

The vertice of the realisable area are

\begin{array}{lll}
   A=(2,0) \\
   B=(0,2) \\
   C=(0,3)\\
   D=(3,4)\\
   E=(4,3)\\
   F=(6,0)
\end{array}

The $(0,0)$ starting point seems not to be a feasible vertice. I have to determine one that could. I thus have to solve an auxiliary linear program.

But I don't know how to do it!
Consequently I tried to solve it in the matrix form but, if my calculations are right, it lead me to a dead end.

The initial set of basic variables are:

$B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$

The associated matrix is therefore:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7\\
3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9\\
3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 18\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$x_1$ enters the basis $B$ and $e_1$ exits.

We multiply to find the new Simplex matrix:

$$B^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

\begin{align}
AB^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 7\\
3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 9\\
3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 18\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 5\\
0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -6\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Which is unexpected.

**therefore, how to know in the matrix form when a linear program isn't feasible, at least from the original method, and what to do with it?**
If you have a method I would be very glad!

Comment: As you pointed out yourself, the feasible area has vertices that you named $A,\cdots,F$. Why don't you use one of these vertices as a starting point?

Comment: @Kuifje thanks for your answers. Because I wanted to do as if I didn't knew them. Should I have tried to find them first? Is it possible when there is a few more variables?